# how to pass dynamic variable in limitTo angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to pass dynamic $scope variable in limitTo

my data array look like as under

```
data = [ key1:'ab',key2:'cd',key3:'ef' ];
```

================================

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
<div>
<label>
{{key}}
</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value | limitTo: {{key}}_No">
{{key1}}
</div>
</div>
```

now problem is that how to pass dynamic key in limitTo means here "{{key}}_No"

i want to result in html

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value | limitTo: key1_No">
    {{key1}}
    </div>
<div ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value | limitTo: key2_No">
    {{key1}}
    </div>
<div ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value | limitTo: key3_No">
    {{key1}}
    </div>
```

how can i achieve this ??????

Comment: `data` is not an array, its a object thus should be like `data = { key1:'ab',key2:'cd',key3:'ef' };
`

Comment: could you try `<div ng-repeat="(key1,value1) in value | limitTo: key + '_No'">`

Comment: sorry is  data = [ key1:'ab',key2:'cd',key3:'ef'   ] just writing mistake

Comment: limitTo: key + '_No' not working tried already @pankajparkar

Comment: just use directive with needed template

Comment: can you provide me example @IgorSemin

Comment: @tapan-bavaliya i don't understand what you want in result page

Comment: shouldn't `limitTo` be just a number? what's the meaning of limitTo: key1_No. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want to achive show more functionality here that's why i need unique scope variable here. @IgorSemin

Comment: i want to achive show more functionality here that's why i need unique scope variable here. @kachhalimbu